# label displays a message when user clicks on save button

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

This might be very simple..but could not figure out. I need to have a label that should not be visible initially and when the user clicks on the "Save" button, that label should be visible with the text "Saving.....". How do i incorporate this in my page. Pasted below is the code for my Save button and the script it calls.

```
       $("#btnSave").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            location.href = '<%: Url.Action("SaveData","Upload") %>';
        });

      <%: Html.SecurityTrimmedSubmitButton(Model.Save_Enabled,"Save Data", "SaveData", "btnSave")%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a div (or label or span or anything)

```
<div id="save_label" style="display:none">Saving...<div>
```

And add the code to show the DIV to your click-handler

```
$("#btnSave").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#save_label").show();
        location.href = '<%: Url.Action("SaveData","Upload") %>';
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

why not add an Ajax Option ?

```
   AjaxOptions fooOptions = new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        UpdateTargetId = "yourDiv",
        LoadingElementId = "spinnerajax",         
    };
```

I believe that the spinnerjax would do exactly what you are trying to achieve 
just add the ajax options to your beginform

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { id = @Model.ID }, fooOptions ))
```